# Issue in uploading file

Tags: php, file, upload

I am trying to upload files 62 Mb.
It giving me following error :

Failed to load resource

I am using following jquery for multiple upload :

```
var form_data = new FormData();                 
     jQuery.each($('#images')[0].files, function(i, file) {
     form_data.append('file[]', file);
       });
     form_data.append("postId", postId) 
        $.ajax({    
            url: '<?php echo get_bloginfo('template_directory') ?>/upload_files.php',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'script/html',
            contentType: 'multipart/form-data',
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            data: form_data, 
            success: function(response) {
                $("#show_progress").hide();
                alert(response);
            },
            error: function() {
                $("#show_progress").hide();
                $("#end_progress").show();
                $("#images").val('');
                }
        });
         }
        });     
});
```

And php file :

```
foreach($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'] as $key =>$tmp_name ) 
{

    $name = $_FILES['file']['name'][$key];
    $tmp_name =  $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$key];                 
    $target_path = $gal_path."/". $_FILES["file"]["name"][$key];
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]['tmp_name'][$key],$target_path);
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO wp_group_upload SET upload_group_id = '$gid', upload_img_name = '$name'");

}
?>
```

Can you tell me what's wrong?

Comment: Depending on whether you are using your own server or not you might have to adjust your php.ini file to change max upload size. I think the defalt is 5MB?

Comment: is `template_directory` a variable in javascript? if it yes, why dont you put `+` between single quotes?

Comment: What is your [`post_max_size`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.post-max-size) or [`upload_max_filesize`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.upload-max-filesize)

Comment: If your PHP doesn't create your jQuery, that `url` won't work.

Answer (score 2):

I think your problem is here :
**See the single quotes!**

```
url: '<?php echo get_bloginfo('template_directory') ?>/upload_files.php'
```

If `template_directory` is a javascript variable, it must be written like this :

```
url: '<?php echo get_bloginfo('+template_directory+') ?>/upload_files.php'
```

If `template_directory` is a string given to `get_bloginfo()` function, it must be written like this :

```
url: '<?php echo get_bloginfo("template_directory") ?>/upload_files.php'
```

or :

```
url: "<?php echo get_bloginfo('template_directory') ?>/upload_files.php"
```